# How to map Elasticsearch match_phrase query in flutter

Tags: flutter, elasticsearch

I am trying to add elasticsearch to my flutter app.
I am using [elastic_client](https://pub.dev/packages/elastic_client) to deal with the connection

How can I map the following query in flutter format?

```
POST /books/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "name" : {
                "query" : "Roberts book",
                "slop": 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is very little info about elasticsearch and flutter.

Right now I have the following code to do the query with elastic_client. But as far as I understand this package did not have the **match_phrase** implemented. And I need to query match_phrase.

```
final searchResult = await client.search(
    index: 'books',
    type: '_doc',
    query: elastic.Query.term('name', ['$searchQuery'.toLowerCase()]),
    source: true);
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVfj_z17O2s&ab_channel=Kiibati) if you want to know more.

- **Update**

With the help of @Vlad and the creator of the [elastic_client](https://github.com/isoos/elastic_client)

It might be useful for someone, so the full solution is:

```
final transport = HttpTransport(url: 'http://myip:9200/');
    final client = elastic.Client(transport);
    final searchResult = await client.search(
      index : 'books',
        type: '_doc',
        query: {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name" : {
              "query" : '$searchQuery'.toLowerCase(),
              "slop": 50,
            },
          },
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the [match implementation](https://pub.dev/documentation/elastic_client/latest/elastic_client/Query/match.html) source code, it looks like that these methods are just wrappers to create JSON. So based on that, I can derive, that you could do the following:

```
final searchResult = await client.search(
    index: 'books',
    type: '_doc',
    query: {
        'match_phrase': {
            'name': {
                'query': '$searchQuery'.toLowerCase(),
                'slop': 50
            }
        },
    };
    source: true);
```

Note, that I have no experience with Flutter, this is just my thinking based on the source code.

Alternatively, you could create your own method which creates JSON for Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. It was only missing the 'name' inside 'match_phase':{}